# VSCode: Test Explorer on remote does not actually execute tests (Python)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I cannot run tests using the Test Explorer in VSCode when connected to a remote machine via SSH. VSCode discovers the tests successfully. When I try to run them, though, VSCode reports that they've run, but does not actually execute anything.
To illustrate, I've set up a directory on a remote machine following VSCode's [official instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing)  for Python testing using pytest. After configuring the Test Explorer, here's what the sidebar looks like:

[image: screenshot of test explorer with tests discovered]

So far, so good.

But when I try to run any of the tests, an interesting thing happens. VSCode reports that the tests have run, but clearly nothing has been executed. I do not get the gutter decorations for the tests as expected, and tests that should be failing do not. (Also, when I set up a test that should take several seconds to execute, it still "executes" in a matter of milliseconds.) Here is what my test output tray looks like:

[image: test console with "successful" tests]

I have also noticed that when I right click on a test in the Test Explorer and select "Go To Test", it actually opens a different file containing the tests, even if the file containing the tests is already open (see the two different files open with the same name in the image below, which are actually the exact same file, but one has a relative path and the other has an absolute path). This new second file has the gutter decorations, but clicking them does the same thing as before (VSCode reports the test executed, but it doesn't have a result).

[image: screenshot of entire vscode window showing two copies of the same file]

I suspect the issue has something to do with my workspace configuration, given that VSCode doesn't "know" that the file is already open when I click "Go To Test". The other thing that makes me think it's a workspace issue is the warning that you can see in the screenshot above about VSCode not being able to watch for changes in this large workspace. The folder that's currently open only has two files in it, so I'm guessing that somewhere VSCode thinks my workspace is larger than the currently open folder (this warning actually appears anytime I open any folder on this remote machine in VSCode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix for anyone coming across this in the future is to **reopen the folder using the absolute path, and ensure there are no symlinks in the path.**

This turned out to be a problem with symlinks. The path to the folder I had open was `~/src/test`. On the remote machine, `~` resolved to `/home/<username>`, which was actually a symlink to `/local/home/<username>`. Evidently VSCode does not follow symlinks, and sometimes [this causes issues](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/19864#issuecomment-1573257297). The fix was simply to reopen the folder at the absolute, non-symlinked path (`/local/home/<username>/src/test`).